# @angular/cli@latest installed still showing angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.28.3

Tags: angular-cli

I have installed latest angular/cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

but when I checked the version it is still showing the older one

i.e angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.28.3

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update

Answer (score 0):

try to uninstall the current version of angular cli with this command:
npm uninstall -g angular-cli

And install again with 
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest